# Unable to create pdf from image using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to create the pdf file from an image file, but getting the blank pdf file.
I draw an image file into the canvas and then trying to create the pdf file.

I am using `html2canvas` and `jspdf`

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rfuajf0/1/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yesterday i got the same task, 
this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/qe884617/

but when exporting pdf you will get a security error about `Tainted canvases may not be exported.` you have to make the image was on the same server as page address. You may read further information [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/182/the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-and-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

This is another approach using fabric.js, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/qe884617/4/) to run you have to Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* on document header. Or just install google chrome CORS addon

Comment: I am not getting any error. pdf is getting downloaded without an image.

I can not change anything on server side. Because it is not in my hand.

Comment: Your code as well generating blank pdf. But here getting the cross-origin issue.

Comment: put to image url location as same as your web server address

Comment: No, I can't do that as well. Image URL always be different from web server address.

Comment: that mean you cant do it, you need server side processing then not only rely on js